# when I fade in a div with an audio player, the audio play button doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, display, tap

I have a splash page with two buttons on it and two content divs that are `display:none`. When you click on one of the two buttons, the content div of your choosing is placed directly under the splash page and the content divs fade in. All this works. But one content div has an audio player. When you click the audio play button, nothing happens. If I take away the `display:none` style, the audio button works, but then my content divs are always visible and I don't want that. Does anyone know what's going on please? Does it have to do with removing a div from the dom and then the page can't "see" the stuff inside the div?

html:

```
<section class="module parallax parallax-1">
      <div class="container1">

      </div>

         <div class="btn_wrapper"><div class="btn" id="btn_pix">Audio Photo Essay</div> <div class="btn" id="btn_text">Story</div></div>

    </section>
    <div id="first_container">

    </div>


    <div id="story_pix" class="story_wrapper">
        <section id="story-start" class="row medium-9 large-7 columns">
            i am the photo story
            <div class="audioPlayer-container">
                <div class="timeline" id="timeline1">
                    <div class="playhead" id="playhead1"></div>
                </div>
                <audio class="audio" id="audio1" src="audio/Audio_IBEW01c.mp3" />
            </div>

            <button id="button1" class="pButton play" ></button> 
            <div class="time_wrapper">
                <span id="time_played1" class="time_played">00:00</span>/<br/>
                <span id="duration1" class="duration">00:45 sec.</span>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>


<div style="margin-top: 50px;"></div>

<div id="story_text" class="story_wrapper" >
        <section class="row medium-9 large-7 columns">
        i am the text story
        </section>
</div><!-- end text story -->
```

style:

```
.btn_wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    top: 85vh;
}
.btn {
    background: white;
    color: #131514;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'proxima-nova', sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.btn:hover {
    background: lightgray;
}
section.module p {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  width: 100%;
    color: #333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    /*padding: 20px 0;*/
}
section.module p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
section.module.content {
  /*padding: 40px 0;*/
}
section.module.parallax {
  height: 1200px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
section.module.parallax-1 {
  background-image: url("../img/ContentForPhotoStory/20170722rldIBEWPhotoStory001_forweb.jpg");
  position: relative;
}
.audioPlayer-container {
    background-size: 85%;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    bottom: -1%;
    margin-top: -62px;
}

audio {
    width: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
.play {
    background: url('../img/headphones-play.png');
}
.pause {
    background: url('../img/headphones-pause.png');
}

.pButton.play,
.pButton.pause {
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    border: none;
    float: left;
    outline: none;
}

.timeline {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 30px 0 0;
    border-top: 0;
    background: #656565;
    height: 10px;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
}

.playhead {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    height: 10px;
    z-index:3;
    border-top: 0;
    background: lightgray;
    border-left: 0px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.time_wrapper {
    border-left: 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    font-family: 'proxima-nova',sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    color: #e8e8e8;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0);
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 36px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    /* transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);*/
    display: inline-block;
}

.story_wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.btn, .storypanel').on('tap', function() {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        var thisChapter = thisID.replace('btn', 'story');
        var thisChapter = thisChapter.replace('panel', 'story');
        $('#' + thisChapter).remove().insertAfter('#first_container');
        $('.story_wrapper').fadeIn();
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#'+thisChapter).offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    //audio player functions
    var playhead;
    var timeline;
    var duration;
    var index;
    var music;

    //iterate through all audio files
    var audios = document.getElementsByClassName("audio");


    //play when play button clicked
    $('.pButton').on('tap', function() {
        var thisIndex = $(this).attr('id');
        thisIndex = parseInt(thisIndex.replace('button', ''));
        music = $('#audio'+thisIndex)[0];
        var pButton = $('#button'+thisIndex);
        playAudio(music, pButton);
    });

    function playAudio(music,pButton) {
        if (music.paused) {
            music.play();
            pButton.attr('class','');
            pButton.attr('class','pButton pause');

        } else {
            music.pause();
            pButton.attr('class','');
            pButton.attr('class','pButton play');
        }
        music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

        var index = $(music).attr('id');
        index = index.replace('audio','');
        timeline = $('#timeline'+index);
        var timelineWidth = timeline.width();

        //Makes timeline clickable
        $(timeline).on("tap", function (event) {
            moveplayhead(event);
            music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
        });

        // returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth
        function clickPercent(event) {
            return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;
        }

        function moveplayhead(event) {
            var newMargLeft = event.clientX - getPosition( timeline );

            if ((newMargLeft != 0) && (newMargLeft != timelineWidth)) {
                playhead.css('margin-left', newMargLeft + "px");
            }
            if (newMargLeft == 0) {
                playhead.css('margin-left', "0px");
            }
            if (newMargLeft >= timelineWidth) {
                playhead.css('margin-left', timelineWidth + "px");
            }
        }

        // Returns elements left position relative to top-left of viewport
        function getPosition(el) {
            return el.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().left;
        }
    }

    function timeUpdate() {
        duration = music.duration;
        var index = music.id;
        index = parseInt(index.replace('audio',''));
        playhead = $("#playhead" + index);           
        var playPercent = 100 * (music.currentTime / duration);
        playhead.css('margin-left', playPercent + "%");
        var time = music.currentTime;
        var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);   
        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
        }
        var seconds = Math.floor(time); 
        if (seconds >= 60) {
            seconds = seconds - 60;
        }
        if (seconds < 10) {
            seconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
        }

        $('#time_played'+index).text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
        if (time == duration) {
            playhead.css('margin-left', '0px');
            $('#time_played'+index).text("00:00");
        }

    }
```

There is a working model of this code here:
[working model](https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/test4/)

Comment: Have you tried using visibility: hidden; in your CSS instead of display:none? The former will include the content in the DOM and the user will not see it while the later is not rendered in the DOM at all. Then you would toggle it to visibility: visible;

Comment: @flyer: I get the same problem with visibility: hidden as with display:none.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo of the music not playing until the section is visible.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.audio-section').css('display', 'block');
    $('audio')[0].play();
  });
});
```

```css
.audio-section {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Show Section</button>

<div class="audio-section">
  <audio src="http://www.vorbis.com/music/Epoq-Lepidoptera.ogg"></audio>
  <div>Here is the section</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but what I need is for the section to appear and then to be able to click the buttons. Right now, the section appears, but the buttons don't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a scoping issue. All the functions about the audio need to be inside the code that handles what to do when the user selects "Audio Photo Essay" or "Story":

```
$('.btn, .storypanel').on('tap', function() {
        var thisID = $(this).attr('id');
        var thisChapter = thisID.replace('btn', 'story');
        var thisChapter = thisChapter.replace('panel', 'story');
        $('#' + thisChapter).remove().insertAfter('#first_container');
        $('.story_wrapper').fadeIn();
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#'+thisChapter).offset().top
        }, 1000);

         //audio player functions
        var playhead;
        var timeline;
        var duration;
        var index;
        var music;

        //play when play button clicked
        $('.pButton').on('tap', function() {
            var thisIndex = $(this).attr('id');
            thisIndex = parseInt(thisIndex.replace('button', ''));
            music = $('#audio'+thisIndex)[0];
            var pButton = $('#button'+thisIndex);
            playAudio(music, pButton);
        }); 

        function playAudio(music,pButton) {
            if (music.paused) {
                music.play();
                pButton.attr('class','');
                pButton.attr('class','pButton pause');

            } else {
                music.pause();
                pButton.attr('class','');
                pButton.attr('class','pButton play');
            }

            music.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);

            var index = $(music).attr('id');
            index = index.replace('audio','');
            timeline = $('#timeline'+index);
            var timelineWidth = timeline.width();

            //Makes timeline clickable
            $(timeline).on("tap", function (event) {
                moveplayhead(event);
                music.currentTime = duration * clickPercent(event);
            });

            // returns click as decimal (.77) of the total timelineWidth
            function clickPercent(event) {
                return (event.clientX - getPosition(timeline)) / timelineWidth;
            }

            function moveplayhead(event) {
                var newMargLeft = event.clientX - getPosition( timeline );

                if ((newMargLeft != 0) && (newMargLeft != timelineWidth)) {
                    playhead.css('margin-left', newMargLeft + "px");
                }
                if (newMargLeft == 0) {
                    playhead.css('margin-left', "0px");
                }
                if (newMargLeft >= timelineWidth) {
                    playhead.css('margin-left', timelineWidth + "px");
                }
            }
          // Returns elements left position relative to top-left of viewport
            function getPosition(el) {
                return el.get(0).getBoundingClientRect().left;
            }
        } //end playAudio

        function timeUpdate() {
            duration = music.duration;
            var index = music.id;
            index = parseInt(index.replace('audio',''));
            playhead = $("#playhead" + index);           
            var playPercent = 100 * (music.currentTime / duration);
            playhead.css('margin-left', playPercent + "%");
            var time = music.currentTime;
            var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);   
            if (minutes < 10) {
                minutes = "0" + minutes.toString();
            }
            var seconds = Math.floor(time); 
            if (seconds >= 60) {
                seconds = seconds - 60;
            }
            if (seconds < 10) {
                seconds = "0" + seconds.toString();
            }

            $('#time_played'+index).text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
            if (time == duration) {
                playhead.css('margin-left', '0px');
                $('#time_played'+index).text("00:00");
            }
        } //end timeUpdate
    }); //$('.btn, .storypanel') tap
```